# No table name set on execute migration in Lumen

Tags: php, laravel, lumen

I'm facing this error when attempting to run the migration in Lumen Framework:

`$ php artisan migrate:install`

```
 [Illuminate\Database\QueryException]                                                                   
  SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1103 Incorrect table name '' (SQL: create table ``  
   (`migration` varchar(255) not null, `batch` int not null) default character set utf8 collate utf8_unicode_ci)     

  [PDOException]                                                                   
  SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1103 Incorrect table name ''
```

And now I have no idea what's going on.

Note that the table that is not being created is the one which controls the migrations at all.

Comment: Neither do we... have you tried googling the error?

Comment: I have, but not found nothing similar. also, I've tried to reinstall the whole system, but still the same error

Comment: In one of your migrations files you have put the table name as blank/empty. Please double check all of the migration files and make sure whether all of them have table names.

Comment: make sure in your migration you have something similar to this :

Schema::create('tableName', function (Blueprint $table) {
//table fields
}

Comment: the migration file is Ok. The one that doesn't work is the migration table, when I run `php artisan migration:install`

Answer (score 49, accepted):

I found the solution myself!

Just add the name of the table on database config array and it's done!

`'migrations' => 'migrations',`

Comment: Works for me, what a silly thing. When you create a custom config/database.php file (in Lumen), you have to add this solution to the main array, on the level of 'connections'.

Comment: This worked for me, I was adding this hint in the wrong place. It should be added outside of the connections map. Check out https://github.com/laravel/lumen-framework/issues/248 for details

Comment: Worked for me as well, that's a quite silly problem as you said; why is it still not the documentation?

Comment: saved my day. tvm

Comment: You're the real god

Comment: Worked for me on fresh install of Lumen8 with mysql8 thanks :D

Answer (score 6):

```
<?php
return [

    'default' => 'external',
    'migrations' => 'migrations',
    'connections' => [
        // your connections
    ],
];
```

Comment: The key here is: you need the `'migrations' => 'migrations'` part.

Comment: It could be kind to add where to put this `config/database.php`

Comment: Please see https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/9.x/config/database.php where to put that part.